# delphi new project not starting at form1

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

So this is just a pet peeve maybe but when I start delphi and start a new project just to test something out I expect it to be form1, unit1, etc. But its starting out new projects at form 2. How can I fix this? I suspected to find a default save space for projects but I did not. I am using delphi 2007 and windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Default directory for new projects is: "RAD Studio/Projects", if in this directory exist project name "Project1.dproj" or "Unit1.pas" then Delphi increase the number for one in your case to Unit2.pas. You can override the old files or change the directory (also create new directory) and save files under different name.
You can also change the default directory in pull down menu:"Tools/Options- 'Environment Options'-'Default project'.

Comment: Delphi behave that way for ages - if I remember correctly, Delphi 1 created new projects that way too.